# Formatting issue while creating new tasks using API

Tags: html, asana

I am automating the "Use as a Template (Copy Project)" action via API but API does not support it directly.

For that, I need to get one "note" from a task and copy it to another task using API, for that I first fetched the task details using API, here is the "notes" tag I received:

> "notes": "\n\nClick on the Down Arrow button to the right of the project
>   \nChoose \"Use as a template (Copy Project)\"\n\nChange
>   the name to:  \"PS - CustomerName - ProjectTitle\"\n(For TM Projects:
>   Change name to \"TM - CustomerName - SENumber (Time)\" )\n\nFind your
>   new project in the project list in the left panel and re-order it
>   alphabetically.\n\nChange the colour."

But when I pass the same "notes" to another task using API, it does not convert \n to new lines, and creating the notes with \n. Can you please suggest me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a "\n" in JSON does indeed map to a newline. If you're using formdata you would need to replace the "\n" with a literal newline character - if you're using JSON, make sure you're not accidentally escaping the "\n" into something like "\n" (or worse).

Comment: Yes you are correct sending it in JSON worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace all instances of "\n" with whatever the new line delimiter is?

Comment: I dont know which new line delimited will work in ASANA.

Comment: A good place to start would be with PHP / whatever, replace the \n with literally a new line (e.g open quotes, press enter, end quotes), to check if it'll handle that.